# Setting more values to 1 in a array?

Tags: c#, arrays

```
class spielfeld
{
    int[,] spielfeldgitter = new int[16, 16];

    public void spielfeldnullsetzen(/*PictureBox pictureBox1*/)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < spielfeldgitter.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < spielfeldgitter.GetLength(1); j++)
            {

                spielfeldgitter[i, j] = 0;

            }
        }
    }

    public void spielfeldol(PictureBox pictureBox1)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
        Graphics feld = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            feld.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 0, (320 / 16) * i, 320, (320 / 16) * i);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            feld.DrawLine(Pens.Black, (320 / 16) * i, 0, (320 / 16) * i, 320);
        }
        pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
    }

    public void mouseclick(int eX, int eY, PictureBox pictureBox1)
    {
        int cellw = (eX / 20);
        int cellh = (eY / 20);
        if (spielfeldgitter[cellw, cellh] != 1)
        {

            spielfeldgitter[cellw, cellh] = 1;
            Graphics rectangle = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image);
            rectangle.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, ((320 / 16) * cellw + 1), (320 / 16) * cellh + 1, (320 / 16) - 1, (320 / 16) - 1);
        }
        else
        {
            spielfeldgitter[cellw, cellh] = 0;
            Graphics rectangle = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image);
            rectangle.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, ((320 / 16) * cellw + 1), (320 / 16) * cellh + 1, (320 / 16) - 1, (320 / 16) - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

SO its the snippet of the src with the logic things im stuck with.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        Feld.spielfeldnullsetzen(/*pictureBox1*/);       
        Feld.spielfeldol(pictureBox1);
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Feld.spielfeldol(pictureBox1);
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int eX = e.X;
        int eY = e.Y;
        Feld.spielfeldol(pictureBox1);
        Feld.mouseclick(eX, eY, pictureBox1);
    }


}
```

thats the form.cs
 my problem is i am creating a 2d array 16,16 big, and set every value to 0. Breakpoint says the same thing when i check it.

then when i do breakpoint at mouseclick
the specific array value changes and the colour of the rectangle too. but i cant manage to make more than one field in another colour

maybe someone can help?

Comment: You have to access every variable. The only way to set multiple is if you are using something like BitArray. Where you can set multiple boolean values because they all read from the same integer.

Answer (score 1):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    spielfeld Feld = new spielfeld();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Load += Form1_Load;
        //pictureBox1.Click += pictureBox1_Click;
        pictureBox1.MouseClick += pictureBox1_MouseClick;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Feld.spielfeldnullsetzen();
        Feld.spielfeldol(pictureBox1);
    }

    //private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    //{
    //    Feld.spielfeldol(pictureBox1);
    //}

    private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int eX = e.X;
        int eY = e.Y;
        //Feld.spielfeldol(pictureBox1);
        Feld.mouseclick(eX, eY, pictureBox1);
    }
}
```

Together with this class

```
class spielfeld
{
    int[,] spielfeldgitter = new int[16, 16];

    public void spielfeldnullsetzen(/*PictureBox pictureBox1*/)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < spielfeldgitter.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < spielfeldgitter.GetLength(1); j++)
            {

                spielfeldgitter[i, j] = 0;

            }
        }
    }

    public void spielfeldol(PictureBox pictureBox1)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
        Graphics feld = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            feld.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 0, (320 / 16) * i, 320, (320 / 16) * i);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            feld.DrawLine(Pens.Black, (320 / 16) * i, 0, (320 / 16) * i, 320);
        }
        pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
    }

    public void mouseclick(int eX, int eY, PictureBox pictureBox1)
    {
        int cellw = (eX / 20);
        int cellh = (eY / 20);
        if (spielfeldgitter[cellw, cellh] != 1)
        {

            spielfeldgitter[cellw, cellh] = 1;
            Graphics rectangle = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image);
            rectangle.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, ((320 / 16) * cellw + 1), (320 / 16) * cellh + 1, (320 / 16) - 1, (320 / 16) - 1);
        }
        else
        {
            spielfeldgitter[cellw, cellh] = 0;
            Graphics rectangle = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image);
            rectangle.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, ((320 / 16) * cellw + 1), (320 / 16) * cellh + 1, (320 / 16) - 1, (320 / 16) - 1);
        }
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Should get you started.

Changes to your original code:

1. `pictureBox1.Refresh()` in the board mouseclick method
2. changes in the form are put in comment

Comment: yes, i have done this changes and when i dont command spielfeldol out it clicks and doing green white again, atleast something more i had before

Comment: [quote] public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Load+=Form1_Load;
            //pictureBox1.Click += pictureBox1_Click;
            //pictureBox1.MouseClick += pictureBox1_MouseClick;
        }[/quote]

Answer (score 0):

That's because `spielfeldol` clears all image and `mouseclick` draws only one rectangle in previously cleared image. So there are few options to fix this:

1. Remove `spielfeldol` method call from `pictureBox1_MouseClick` event handler and add some kind of button to call `spielfeldol` method for clearing image.
2. In `spielfeldol` method reuse `pictureBox1.Image` (do not create new Bitmap - it will be empty) like you do in 'mouseclick' method.

Comment: hm, ok but when i do a outcommand of the spielfeldol it wont draw anything  when i click how can i fix this? i am a beginner

Comment: the button resets the field now, but what do you mean with reuse, atleast how? :D